# Delete files from a folder based on another file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a text file named input.txt as shown below.

```
adva
abab
dfg1
672a
```

I have a folder named folder1 which contain a list of files like adva.txt, dfg1.txt, asd2.txt etc. In folder1, I need to keep only the file names which are present in input.txt. Other files should remove from the folder1.

your suggestions would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it requires mass deletion of file I would highly recommend **safety approach**. Consider this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# rename folder1
mv folder1 _folder1

# create a new dir folder1
mkdir folder1

# copy required files from _folder1 to folder1
while read l; do
    cp _folder1/$l.txt folder1
done < input.txt
```

After this script has run verify all the files in folder1, if satisfied then only remove folder and all files in `_folder1` using:

```
rm -rf _folder1
```